# Using textbox to gather user's destination path for exporting a CSV in C# Windows application?

Tags: c#, csv, input, directory

I'm looking for an option that allows a user to input their destination folder (Usually copy/Paste) into a text box on a Windows Application, and append the file's name with a specific name. However, I'm stuck as to how to accomplish this.

```
//Exporting to CSV.
        string folderPath = MessageBox.Show(textBox1_TextChanged);
        File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv", csv);
```

So it can look like: C:/DIR_9132017.csv, or Documents/DIR_9132017.csv, depending on what the user inputs into the textbox. I have nothing in my textbox code section at the moment, if that also gives a clearer picture about the situation.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Use a `FolderBrowserDialog` control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use FolderBrowserDialog or can just copy/paste the path and create the directory.

Using FolderBrowserDialog 
Step1 : Create Browse button (so that the user can choose the directory)
Step2 : Create Export button (Place the code to write the file here)

```
private void browseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                var folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
                textBox1.Text = folderPath;
            }
        }



   private void exportToCsvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
                {
                    var path = textBox1.Text;
                    var file = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    var filename =  "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv";
                    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "test.csv"), "content");
                }
```

Using Copy/Paste

Step1 : Create Export button (User copy pastes the path. System create the directory and writes the file)

```
private void exportToCsvButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var path = textBox1.Text;
                var file = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
var filename =  "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv";
                File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "test.csv"), "content");
            }
```

Comment: It's saying csv is undefined. How would I fix this? By setting it to a blank string? Because if I do that, then I get an access denied error.

Comment: The csv is the content, the one you have mentioned in your code File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "DIR_" + (DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()) + ".csv", csv);

Comment: It just takes the program a LONG time to try to do the function.

Comment: It does not take even a second to create the directory. May be cause your csv file is too big, it is taking time to write. I have answered the question regarding creating a file, that you have asked. If you have some other issue, please explain.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if I upset you. It does work when I try the test.csv one, so that's a plus. The program will be used for big csv files however.

Comment: No problem. If it is working for you, could you please mark this as answer to the asked question. The large file issue you can explain further as another question and people will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a FolderBrowserDialog for that.  After adding it to your form, you can use it like this:

```
public void ChooseFolder()
{
    if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        folderPath = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984305(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified whether it's WinForms or WPF, so I'm using WPF, but is should be the same in WinForms.

To select the folder, you could use `FolderBrowseDialog` as follows. This code should be placed inside a button or some other similar control's `Click` event.

```
if (folderBrowse.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    txtPath.Text = folderBrowse.SelectedPath;
}
```

`txtPath` being a `TextBox` your selected path displayed in. You can substitute it with a simple `string` variable if you don't want to use a `TextBox`.

And if you want the user to be able to drag-drop a folder into a `TextBox`, you can create a `TextBox` control, and in it's `PreviewDragOver` and `Drop` events, you can do the following.

```
private void txtPath_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void txtPath_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
    if (files != null && files.Length != 0)
        txtPath.Text = files[0];
}
```

Using both above in combination user has the ability to either select the folder he/she wants by clicking a button, drag-and-drop a folder into the `TextBox`, or copy-paste the folder path into the `TextBox`.